# newif for table does not work

Tags: pgfplotstable, ifthenelse

I create two different table contents and want to switch with a newif. `\AAAfalse` has no effect.  What do I have to do?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableset{string type, col sep=comma, header=false}

\newif\ifAAA
\AAAtrue

\ifAAA%================================
\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{
A, A
A, A
A, A
}\mytable
\def\mycolor{red}
\else%==================================
\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{
B, B
B, B
B, B
}\mytable
\def\mycolor{blue}
\fi%=====================================

\begin{document}
\section{\color{\mycolor} AAA true :)}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{\mytable}

\AAAfalse
\section{\color{\mycolor} AAA false :(}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You've read the table inside the conditional, changing it afterwards does nothing. Did you meant to save the setup inside a macro which itself contains the conditional?

Comment: Yes, I think so. After \AAAfalse should come the table with the B's.

Comment: you don't test the boolean at any point after `\AAAfalse` so naturally it has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you switch the `\ifAAA` you have already read the table; the macro `\mytable` has already been defined and it will not change. One possibility is to make the loading of the table dynamic (I had to change the termination because when into a macro, the newlines are changed to space tokens and that make the inline table unreadable):

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableset{string type, col sep=comma, header=false}

\newif\ifAAA
\AAAtrue

\def\loadtable{%
\ifAAA
\pgfplotstableread[header=false, row sep=crcr]{%
A, A \\
A, A \\
A, A \\
}\mytable
\def\mycolor{red}%
\else
\pgfplotstableread[header=false, row sep=crcr]{%
B, B \\
B, B \\
B, B \\
}\mytable
\def\mycolor{blue}%
\fi}

\begin{document}
\loadtable
\section{\color{\mycolor} AAA true :)}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{\mytable}

\AAAfalse
\loadtable
\section{\color{\mycolor} AAA false :(}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Surely there are more elegant solutions, like defining two tables and switching on loading, but I got lost with `\expandafter`s (I should seriously learn more LaTeX3).

Comment: It's only now that I've noticed that: 
it is not so good if you have to change the table. With such a small MWE it doesn't matter much, but in real case....

Comment: You can load the two tables with different names and then put the "if" around the `\pgfplotstable` command, for example...